# Recurrence Relation with Variable Coefficient Help

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm sure that this question is very simple, but there are no example like it in the course material and I'm not really sure what I'm looking for online.

$x_n=2^n x_{n-1}, x_0=3$

If anybody could even point me to a website that explained this, that would be great!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x_1=2\cdot x_0\\x_2=2^2x_1=2^{2+1}x_0\\x_3=2^3x_2=2^{3+2+1}x_0\\\dots\\x_{n}=2^{n+(n-1)+\cdots+1}x_0=2^{\frac{n^2+n}{2}}x_0.$$

Comment: @user222031 thanks for catching that!